# Finding a map in list/vector of maps in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, find, scala-collections, scalaz

I have a vector/list of maps (`Map[String,Int]`). How can I find if a key-value pair exists in one of these maps in the list of maps using `.find`?

Answer (score 2):

```
val res = List(Map("1" -> 1), Map("2" -> 2)).find(t => t.exists(j => j == ("2", 2)))
println(res)
```

use `find` with `exists` to check whether it exists in maps.

Comment: I suggest that you use [===](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Equal.html) as a minor improvement for more type safety. Avoid `==` at all costs - `@ "42" == 1234` returns `res14: Boolean = false` on the REPL.

Answer (score 1):

chengpohi's solution is pretty inefficient, and also different to how I understand the question.

Let `m: Map[String,Int]`.

### Why chengpoi's solution is inefficient

First, using `m.exists(j => j == ("2",2))`, which can also be written `m.contains("2" -> 2)` looks at every entry of `m`, while `m("2").toSeq.contains(2)` performs only a single map lookup.
Note that `m.contains("2" -> 2)` will not work, as `contains` is overridden for `Map` to check for a key, i.e., `m.contains("2")` works—and is also fast.

To obtain the same result as chengpoi, but efficiently:

```
def mapExists[K,V](ms: List[Map[K,V]], k: K, v: V): Option[(K,V)] = 
    ms.get(k).filter(_ == v).map(_ => k -> v)
```

Note that this method returns its arguments, which is quite redundant.

### How I understand the question

Second, I understood the question as checking whether the `List` contains a `Map` with a specific pair.
This would translate to

```
def mapExists[K,V](ms: List[Map[K,V]], k: K, v: V): Boolean = 
    ms.exists(_.get(k).contains(v))
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done even like this using just the key value we are interested to find:

```
scala> val res = List(Map("A" -> 10), Map("B" -> 20)).find(_.keySet.contains("B"))
res: Option[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int]] = Some(Map(B -> 20))

scala>
```